# Using PHP 8.1 on Mac OS 10.13 with Vhost

Tags: php, macos, apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

Trying to use `PHP 8.1` on `localhost` with `Mac OS High Sierra (10.13.6)`.
Note that I also want to keep PHP 7.4, because I still need it for older projects.

It doesn't work and error logs shows nothing.

**What I did so far**

- Installed PHP 8.1 using brew `brew install php@8.1`
- Edited and sourced `.zshrc` with the path

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/sbin:$PATH"
```

- Edited `httpd.conf`, added the following line `LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so` and commented other php modules
- Edited `httpd-vhosts.conf` with the following conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-project.local
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/my-project"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/my_project-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/my_project-access_log" common
    <Directory  "/Library/WebServer/Documents/my-project/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- edited `/etc/hosts/`, added the domain :
  `127.0.0.1  my-project.local`
- restarted apache `sudo apachectl restart`

**Result**

The `index.php` file is read, but PHP is not working.

I've put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` + some random HTML on my index.php, when opening http://my-project.local with Firefox I only see the HTML, phpinfo is not showing, not even as plain text, just blank.
When reaching http://my-project.local with Chrome I see the PHP as plain text.

**Notes**

- When switching back to PHP 7.4, everything works fine
- Tried to add the following code to `httpd.conf`

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

but it doesn't help, actually in this case `index.php` is not read and I got the error `The connection has been reset` but nothing is shown in error logs, either access logs.

I don't understand what's going on, everything seems good to me, if somebody could help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain `The index.php file is read, but PHP is not working` - you get errors (assuming error reporting is _on_), get PHP code back as plain text, etc?

Comment: Hi, I've put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` + some random HTML on my `index.php`, when opening `http://my-project.local` I only see the HTML, phpinfo is not showing, not even as plain text, just blank. 
Just tried to add error reporting with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and still the same result : nothing but HTML is shown, but no PHP as plain text or error

Comment: edit: in Chrome I actually see the PHP as plain text. On Firefox it's hidden. Will edit my post accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to add `index.php` to `DirectoryIndex` which had only `index.html`

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

Now everything works fine